# YII Fatal Error: Call To A Member Function Of A Non Object

Tags: php, yii

anyone can help me?
I got stuck of this code.

```
$billing->bookingHeader->getCodeNumber('BKG');
```

Actually $billing is a model and bookingHeader is the relation.

this line generate error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCodeNumber() on a non-object
```

Below is the component contains result.

```
class MonthlyTransactionActiveRecord extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function getCodeNumber($cnConstant = '')
    {
        $arr = array('I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XI', 'XII');
        $month = $this->cn_month ? $this->cn_month - 1 : 0;
        return sprintf('%02d/%04d/%s/%s/%02d', $this->hotel_id, $this->cn_ordinal, $cnConstant, $arr[$month], $this->cn_year);
    }
}
```

I call `$billing->bookingHeader->getCodeNumber('BKG');` twice (in view and controller), it has no error in view, but when I call it in Controller, it gives me error.

What kind of trigger the error has? How to fix that?
Thank you..

Comment: Seems like the bookingHeader is null.

Comment: try MonthlyTransaction->getCodeNumber('BKG');

Answer (score 0):

Check the object weather it's empty or not before you invoke it's method.

```
if($billing->bookingHeader){
  $billing->bookingHeader->getCodeNumber('BKG');
}else{
  echo "bookingHeader is empty";
}
```